# Set TCP/IP protocol enable for SQL Server 2008 r2 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing SQL Server settings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266697/changing-sql-server-settings-programmatically)

To setup a network connection between client C# application and SQL Server 2008 R2 I know what should manually do, my problems is how to do following steps in the C# code!

1. Set TCP/IP protocol Enabled for a server instance like `MSSQLSERVERR2`.
2. Restart my SQL Server engine.

   I can do the other steps by SQL queries:
3. Add User and grant admin permission.

   ```
   CREATE LOGIN momtahen 
   WITH PASSWORD = '123'

   EXEC master..sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'momtahen', 
                                    @rolename = N'sysadmin'
   ```
4. Set mixed authentication mode for my SQL Server.

   ```
   EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
   N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
   ```

I need C# code or SQL query that I could execute using C#.

Also I have to mention that I have seen following question and no help yet!

- [Enable tcp\ip remote connections to sql server express already installed database with code or script(query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138172/enable-tcp-ip-remote-connections-to-sql-server-express-already-installed-databas)
- [Enable remote connections to sql express with a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137836/enable-remote-connections-to-sql-express-with-a-script/9154540#9154540)
- [what are registry settings to enable TCP on SQL Server 2005 and 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499957/what-are-registry-settings-to-enable-tcp-on-sql-server-2005-and-2008)

Thanks to them by the way. So any Idea?

Comment: The options seem to have been discussed here already: [Changing SQL Server settings programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266697/changing-sql-server-settings-programmatically) It would help if you can explain why none of the other questions are helpful, and also if you're installing SQL Server then the suggestion to use a silent installation with a configuration file would be an alternative.

Comment: I couldn't find or write the C# code!

Comment: I found the code, I'll post it in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266697/changing-sql-server-settings-programmatically) since this thread is closed.